# Determining Error via IAsyncResult that has WebRequest WebResponse in C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, iasyncresult

I'm working on a Windows Phone app. Usually I would use a `WebClient` however, in this specific case I've been told that I need to use a `HttpWebRequest`. I can successfully fire off the request. However, occassionally it fails. Either because of a network issue or an exception thrown by the server. How do I detect an error associated with the `IAsyncResult` approach? Currently, I have the following:

```
private void HttpWebRequest_Completed(IAsyncResult result)
{
  WebRequest request = (WebRequest)(result.AsyncState);
  WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);

  // Detect if there was an error right here. 
  ...
}
```

My code works fine unless there was an error. I'm not sure how to detect errors though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd expect `EndGetResponse` to throw the same exception which would be thrown directly if you'd called the synchronous `GetResponse` method.

Comment: How do I detect something like a 404 though?

Comment: @JavaScriptDeveloper: The same way you would with a synchronous call. Catch the `WebException` and fetch the status on the response.